# how to extract a part of file name in unix scripting and check if it exists

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I need to write a script where I have to extract part of the name from a file `abc_def_xxx_yyy_20210515.txt` and check if  `abc_def_xxx_yyy.txt` exists. If not then create the file.

```
FILE="abc_def_xxx_yyy_20210515.txt"
DLS=echo $FILE | awk -F_ '{print $1,$2,$3,$4".txt"}'
DLL=\home\xxx\$DLS
if [-f "$DLL"]; then
echo "$DLL exists"
else 
touch "$DLL"
fi
```

I get the error saying `"abc_def_xxx_yyy_20210515.txt" not found`

but if I just run with

```
FILE="abc_def_xxx_yyy_20210515.txt"
echo $FILE | awk -F_ '{print $1,$2,$3,$4".txt"}'
```

I get `abc_def_xxx_yyy.txt`.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `ksh`?

Comment: There are a bunch of syntax errors here; run it through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fix what it points out. Also, it looks you're using DOS/Windows paths (with `/` rather than `\`) -- is this on Windows or Unix/Linux?

Comment: Is on UNIX path

Comment: And I am using ksh

Comment: You forgot the `$(...)` around the command substitution. You are assigning the string `echo` to the variable `DLS` and then attempting to execute `$FILE` as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
FILE="abc_def_xxx_yyy_20210515.txt"
DLS="${FILE%_*}.txt"
DLL="$HOME/$DLS"
if [ -f "$DLL"]; then
  echo "$DLL exists"
else 
  touch "$DLL"
fi
```